# two column with same grouping priority in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, grouping, angular-ui-grid

maybe the title of my question is not proper, please feel free to update my title.

my json data is like

```
    [
        { "AutoId": 2, "CustomerId": "1000AIRLIESST", "customerLastName": "John", "locationId": "2", "Address": "1000   AIRLIES ST Winnipeg " },
        { "AutoId": 2, "CustomerId": "1000AIRLIESST", "customerLastName": "John", "locationId": "186471", "Address": "1000 Airlies ST Winnipeg " },
        { "AutoId": 2, "CustomerId": "1000AIRLIESST", "customerLastName": "John", "locationId": "186752", "Address": "111   pineview rd ST Winnipeg " }
    ];
```

as you can see the autoId, customerId and lastname are same. I want to demonstrate this data in ui-grid like following picture. I want to common part of my data comes in main columns.

[image]

Comment: use `ng-repeat` its easy mode. put your data on scope and repeat it in a table or something.

Comment: yes,  this is first solution, but I'd like to use ui-grid as well. anyway thanks

Comment: i think that you have to elaborate the data before in your controller and then pass it to your view,  you could iterate the raw data and then create a new array to pass the view.

Comment: missed th ui grid part. cesar is right get the data in the form you want and then pass to grid.

Comment: I think data format is fine, because now I can group it based on customerId and it works well. the problem is I cannot bring the lastname in grouped row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to group two column with same grouping priority

> groupPriorities should generally be sequential, if they're not then the next time getGrouping is called we'll renumber them to be sequential. 
>   Defaults to undefined.

so my solution is like a cheat. first I use the aggregation function (max) for second column (customerLastname). then I used a custom directive to manipulate data.
**you can see the result in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpFjW3V2HZ4HvUFeArb5?p=preview)**

The column definition of ui-grid

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
        columnDefs: [
                 {
                     name: 'customerLastName',
                     displayName: 'Customer LastName',
                     width: 200,
                     treeAggregationType: uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.MAX,
                     cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" > <fakemax val="{{COL_FIELD}}" /></div>'

                 },
                 {
                     name: 'Address',
                     width: 200,
                 },

                {
                    name: 'CustomerId',
                    grouping: { groupPriority: 0 },
                    sort: { priority: 0, direction: 'desc' },
                    width: 200,
                    cellTemplate: '<div><div ng-if="!col.grouping || col.grouping.groupPriority === undefined || col.grouping.groupPriority === null ||' +
                        ' ( row.groupHeader && col.grouping.groupPriority === row.treeLevel )" class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div></div>'
                },
        ],
        data: 'Customers',
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }

    };
```

please pay attention to fakemax directive which I used in the cellTemplate of customerLastName. the custom directive is so simple.

```
app.directive('fakemax', function () {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        var value = iAttrs.val;
        value = value.replace("max:", "");
        iElement[0].innerHTML = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe they still don't allow multiple top-level (or "n"-level) groups.  Your solution solved my problem, though.

Comment: The plunkr doesnt seem to load anymore, kindly review your post again..

Comment: Yes, it does now.. maybe plunkr was down when I tried.. thanks anyways.. also is it possible to group on one field and get value for another field?